# AVL Tree rotations : How to balance below AVL Tree with imbalance at root node

Tags: binary-trees, binary-search-trees

[image: **Insertion of item 5 causes imbalance at root level**]]

How to balance this AVL tree after inserting node 5, using left/right rotations as indicated in [the AVL tree tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm). I have tried applying both double rotations but with no luck. Either of the double rotations still ends up producing a tree with imbalance as indicated above.

Do you mean the below solution?

[image]

Comment: Can you perform a right rotation at node 7 on the bottom right graph?

Comment: Do you mean the above diagram solution in 2 step iteration? I added it to original question since cant add images to replies here.

Comment: Basically you are right. However, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my goodness. [That AVL tree tutorial at tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm) is so misleading that it is the reason why you became confused. Please ignore that tutorial.

Please study [the AVL tree insertion article at GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/) instead. Or check some textbook such as *Introduction to Algorithms* by By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. This recommendation should be one of the best help you can get from asking a question.

In the graph you last uploaded, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HivT.png, the change from the first tree directly to the last tree is called a right rotation by almost every textbook, tutorial and articles I have seen. The tree in the middle never appears. The tree in the middle is just an extra unnecessary distracting step.

Comment: Noted. Thank you. I was trying to follow the steps given in tutorialspoint on rotations. will check the CLRS book.